# Can we add 2 nodes to a cluster in parallel?

Tags: cassandra

We want to increase our Cassandra Cluster database from 1 to 3. The current Cassandra DB already has data in it (50/100 GB).

Can we add both new nodes at the same time? Or should we add one by one until the sync is fully finished before adding the second new one to the cluster?

Thanks for the help and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add nodes one at a time, waiting for each node to completely finish the bootstrap process, before you can add the next node.

Until a node finishes bootstrapping, it doesn't fully own the tokens yet. If you add another node to the cluster, there is a potential for a collision in the token assignments where a node takes ownership of the same token as another joining node.

Also, the existing node in the cluster can get overloaded by multiple requests from the new nodes to stream data. Cheers!